# UIBezierPath Rectangle with Circular Handles

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a rectangle which has four circular handles.  Here's what it would look like:

```
o----o
|    |
|    |
o----o
```

The circular handles are "hot".  In other words, when the user touches it, the handle can be moved around while the rest of the points are anchored.  I wanted to know if anyone had an approach for coding this functionality.  I'm looking at UIBezierPath to draw the rectangle with circles, but I'm having a hard time thinking about how to allow the user to tap only the circles.  I was thinking it may need to be five different UIBezierPath objects, but eventually the UI will consist of multiples of these objects.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What about `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` ?
You know when to stop the "straight line"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't draw it as a single shape with complicated `UIBezierPath`s at all. I'd think about it as 6 different pieces. A Container, a rectangle, and 4 circles.

I would have a simple container `UIView` that has a rectangle view and four circular `UIViews` at its corners. Then put a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on each circle. In the gesture handler, move the center of the circle and adjust the underlying rectangle rect by the same amount. This will avoid any complicated paths or math and make it simple add and subtract amounts on the rectangle itself.

**Update: Code!**

I created a self contained UIView subclass that handles everything. You can create one like so:

```
HandlesView *view = [[HandlesView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view];

// A custom property that contains the selected area of the rectangle. Its updated while resizing.
[view setSelectedFrame:CGRectMake(128.0, 128.0, 200.0, 200.0)];
```

The frame of the view itself is the total draggable area. The selected frame is the inner visible rectangle.

```
//
//  HandlesView.h
//  handles
//
//  Created by Ryan Poolos on 2/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Ryan Poolos. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface HandlesView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGRect selectedFrame;

@end
```

And here is the implementation.

```
//
//  HandlesView.m
//  handles
//
//  Created by Ryan Poolos on 2/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Ryan Poolos. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HandlesView.h"

@interface HandlesView ()
{
    UIView *rectangle;

    NSArray *handles;
    NSMutableArray *touchedHandles;

    UIView *circleTL;
    UIView *circleTR;
    UIView *circleBL;
    UIView *circleBR;
}
@end

@implementation HandlesView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 22.0, 22.0)];
        [self addSubview:rectangle];

        // Create the handles and position.
        circleTL = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0)];
        [circleTL setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle.frame))];

        circleTR = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0)];
        [circleTR setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle.frame))];

        circleBL = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0)];
        [circleBL setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle.frame))];

        circleBR = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0)];
        [circleBR setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle.frame))];

        handles = @[ circleTL, circleTR, circleBL, circleBR ];

        for (UIView *handle in handles) {
            // Round the corners into a circle.
            [handle.layer setCornerRadius:(handle.frame.size.width / 2.0)];
            [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

            // Add a drag gesture to the handle.
            [handle addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]];

            // Add the handle to the screen.
            [self addSubview:handle];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelectedFrame:(CGRect)selectedFrame
{
    [rectangle setFrame:selectedFrame];

    [circleTL setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle.frame))];
    [circleTR setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMinY(rectangle.frame))];
    [circleBL setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle.frame))];
    [circleBR setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectangle.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(rectangle.frame))];
}

- (CGRect)selectedFrame
{
    return rectangle.frame;
}

// Forward the background color.
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    // Set the container to clear.
    [super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Set our rectangle's color.
    [rectangle setBackgroundColor:[backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];

    for (UIView *handle in handles) {
        [handle setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    }
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // The handle we're moving.
    UIView *touchedHandle = gesture.view;

    // Keep track of touched Handles.
    if (!touchedHandles) {
        touchedHandles = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            [touchedHandles addObject:touchedHandle];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            CGPoint tranlation = [gesture translationInView:self];

            // Calculate this handle's new center
            CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(touchedHandle.center.x + tranlation.x, touchedHandle.center.y + tranlation.y);

            // Move corresponding circles
            for (UIView *handle in handles) {
                if (handle != touchedHandle && ![touchedHandles containsObject:handle]) {
                    // Match the handles horizontal movement
                    if (handle.center.x == touchedHandle.center.x) {
                        handle.center = CGPointMake(newCenter.x, handle.center.y);
                    }

                    // Match the handles vertical movement
                    if (handle.center.y == touchedHandle.center.y) {
                        handle.center = CGPointMake(handle.center.x, newCenter.y);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Move this circle
            [touchedHandle setCenter:newCenter];

            // Adjust the Rectangle
            // The origin and just be based on the Top Left handle.
            float x = circleTL.center.x;
            float y = circleTL.center.y;

            // Get the width and height based on the difference between handles.
            float width = abs(circleTR.center.x - circleTL.center.x);
            float height = abs(circleBL.center.y - circleTL.center.y);

            [rectangle setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

            [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
        }
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [touchedHandles removeObject:touchedHandle];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

This is only a proof of concept. There are a lot of missing caveats like being able to drag outside the box, multitouch complications, negative sizes. All these problems can be handled very differently and are the secret sauce that makes something like this go from a nice idea to a beautiful custom interface. I'll leave that part up to you. :)

Comment: I really like this approach a lot.  It seems extremely simple.  Do you see any performance issues with using this approach when there could be multiple of these objects on the screen at once?

Comment: I don't expect to. I decided to throw a bit of code into it. So give me 5 minutes and I'll have a small example you can try out.

Comment: Added some code :) hope it helps you get started. Tried to leave some helpful comments but if you have more questions don't hesitate.

Comment: This is an excellent starting point!  It makes translation much easier than having to deal with multiple layers, etc.  Huge thumbs up!  If I have any other questions I'll post them on here.

Comment: Glad I could help, Happy Coding :) P.S. would love to see some of your solutions to the problems I mentioned.

Comment: I'll post them up as I go along!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24459/discussion-between-user833999-and-ryan-poolos)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to store the circle bezier paths in your class for when you implement gesture recognizers.

There is an Apple document describing how to implement a UIView or UIControl that accepts touch events with pictures and sample code.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9